# How to create a nested dictionary from a given dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I got a df like this one:

```
level       profile    chest_gold       chest_silver        chest_bronze
1           a          TRUE             FALSE               TRUE
2           a          FALSE            FALSE               TRUE
3           a          FALSE            TRUE                TRUE
```

I want to obtain a dictionary which uses as key the level and the profile to return something like this, converting the TRUE/FALSE in 1/0:

```
d[profile][level] = [1, 0, 1]  #the chest result
```

for example:

```
d['a'][1] = [1,0,1]
d['a'][2] = [0,0,1]
d['a'][3] = [0,1,1]
```

How can I do that?

P.s. if you leave a solution please leave also a little comment to explain the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Check a nested dictionary comprehension. The inner comprehension builds dictionary where keys are levels and outer comprehension builds a dictionary where the keys are profiles.

```
output = {k: {i: v for i, *v in d.set_index('level').filter(like='chest').astype(int).to_records()} for k, d in df.groupby('profile')}

{'a': {1: [1, 0, 1], 2: [0, 0, 1], 3: [0, 1, 1]}}
```